# Too many requests per second api vk node js

Tags: node.js, vkontakte-api

Выполняю  метод из API ВК несколько раз, сервер возвращает ошибку "too many requests per second". Как можно обойти ее? (Node js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выполнять [ограничения на количество запросов в секунду](https://vk.com/dev/api_requests), накладываемые VK.

> Со стороны клиента можно обращаться к методам API **не чаще 3 раз в секунду**.
>
> Максимальное число запросов со стороны сервера зависит от числа пользователей, установивших приложение.
>   Если приложение установило меньше 10 000 человек, то можно совершать 5 запросов в секунду, до 100 000 – 8 запросов, до 1 000 000 – 20 запросов, больше 1 млн. – 35 запросов в секунду.
>
> При превышении этих значений сервер вернет ошибку с кодом 6: "Too many requests per second.".

Решение указано на той же странице:

> Если логика Вашего приложения подразумевает вызов нескольких методов подряд, имеет смысл обратить внимание на метод [execute](https://vk.com/dev/execute).

Ну или просто делать меньше запросов в секунду, собственно.

Comment: а как сделать  меньше запросов? задержкой? Можно пожалуйста пример

Comment: @dimaborovski Попробуйте `setTimeout`. Попробуйте пройтись по ссылке `execute`.

Comment: @dimaborovski если запросы выполняются в бесконечном цикле, можно делать `continue` при получении ответа с такой ошибкой.